# For the set X = { 2,3,6,12,24,36}, a relation ≤ is defined as x ≤ y if x divides y. Draw the Hasse diagram for (X,≤)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For the set X = { 2,3,6,12,24,36}, a relation ≤ is defined as x ≤ y if x divides y.
Draw the Hasse diagram for (X,≤) . Answer the following:
(i) What are the maximal and minimal elements?
(ii) Give one example of chain & antichain.
(iii) Is the poset a lattice?

I have tried to solve this question as follows:

R={(2,2),(2,6),(2,12),(2,24),(2,36),(6,6),(6,12),(6,24),(6,36),(12,12),(12,24),(12,36),(24,24),(3,3),(3,6),(3,12),(3,24),(3,36)}

Final hasse diagram:

[image]

Maximal Elements:24,36
Minimal Elements: 2,3
Chain={2,6,12,24}
antichain={2,3}
This poset is not a lattice.

is the answer correct.